# How to access User Picture field for a comment in Views?

Tags: views, media

I have a Views table with each row showing the node title, node author, and node author picture. I am also adding the last comment title and last comment author to each table row. I would like to add the last comment user picture but that doesn't seem possible from looking at the code.

There is a database table called Node Comment Statistics which Views uses to query the last comment author name and UID.

I would like to somehow use that last comment UID to query the database for the user picture and render it through the theme_user_picture function adding it the View or attaching it someway to the Username with some markup.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

1. Add a relationship- Comments: User
2. Add a field- User: Picture (assign Relationship: User)